# Run emulator error

Tags: android

When I run the emulator, the following error log is given:

```
12-01 12:33:40.900: E/logwrapper(41): executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
12-01 12:33:41.020: E/logwrapper(44): executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
12-01 12:33:43.600: E/cutils(56): Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
12-01 12:33:50.100: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): hwcomposer module not found
12-01 12:33:53.010: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
12-01 12:33:54.880: E/AudioFlinger(55): int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
12-01 12:34:17.380: E/memtrack(53): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-01 12:34:17.380: E/android.os.Debug(53): failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-01 12:34:40.450: E/logwrapper(318): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
12-01 12:34:40.540: E/logwrapper(319): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
12-01 12:34:40.620: E/logwrapper(320): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
12-01 12:34:40.670: E/logwrapper(321): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
12-01 12:34:40.860: E/logwrapper(322): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
12-01 12:34:40.940: E/logwrapper(323): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
12-01 12:34:41.070: E/logwrapper(325): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
12-01 12:34:49.790: E/EmojiFactory_jni(53): Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
12-01 12:36:16.980: E/PowerManagerService-JNI(438): Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
12-01 12:36:20.770: E/SurfaceFlinger(52): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

[image]
[image]

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Which emulator did you run ? How ?

Comment: Hi,gahfy.
I uploaded two pictures about emulator.
Thank you.

Comment: Speaking generally, it should be noted that lots of errors in logcat, especially on the first run of an emulator instance, is not unusual and may not indicate a problem.  The emulator may require many minutes to initialize.